# XML not picking up <camelContext> tag

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel, xml-namespaces

this is probably a simple mis configuration problem but I am having an issue with my xml document picking up my  tag. I am getting the error

"Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
    - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'camelContext' of schema namespace 'http://activemq.apache.org/camel/"

But when I add in the namespace I get the following error:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'camelContext'.
    - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd', because 1) could not 
     find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
    - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'camelContext' of schema namespace 'http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring'

Can anyone help me figure out why I am getting both of these issues? I am not expert in xml or camel so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below is my simple xml document:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring     http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">



   <bean id="myrouter"      class="org.apache.camel.example.reportincident.ReportIncidentRoutes"/>



<!-- Camel Configuration -->

 <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilderRef ref="myrouter"/>


 </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: Here is the reference and issue resolution  - https://developer.jboss.org/thread/267282

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Camel 1.x the namespace for the XML is the one that start with activemq, eg

```
xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/camel/schema/spring"
```

In Camel 2.x the namespace for the XML is pure Camel, eg

```
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
```

As Camel 1.x is EOL I assume you are using Camel 2.x. And if so you need to change t he namespace in the < camelContext > tag to the 2.x style. And remove the old reference as well in the top of your XML file.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you by chance the guy that wrote the Report Incident tutorial on apache camel website? It has been a great help so far but I was hoping you had finished the part about using Spring xml for routing. Any idea when that will be done?

Comment: Ah yeah the old tutorial I wrote like 4.5 - 5 years ago. http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident.html - the source code is here https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/examples/camel-example-reportincident/ and has been updated to the current release.

Comment: Thank you! I have been having a lot of issues understanding how to go from the Java route building to convert it over to using spring for routing. I just took a look at this source and this will help a lot. thank you for all the effort you have put into making that tutorial!

Comment: i still have the same problem with camel 2.11.0. Any help?

Comment: @hoshang.varshney a little late but you will need to add this to the beans  tag on xsi:schemaLocation property: http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! I have older version of JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 and my route was working fine. but in JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 I got **XML not picking up < camelContext > tag**. after I added http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd to xsi:schemaLocation and it's works!!!